# Loopback email connector connect ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: javascript, email, loopback

I see that loopback documents to use email connector at [email connector](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Email-connector.html)
My email datasource in datasources.js as below :

```
"emailDataSource": {
"name": "emailDataSource",
"connector": "mail",
"transports":[{
  "type":"SMTP",
  "host": "stmp.gmail.com",
  "secure":true,
  "port":50,
  "auth":{
    "user":"test@gmail.com",
    "pass":"pass"
  }
}]}
```

And my config in model-config.json

```
"Email":{
"dataSource":"emailDataSource"}
```

And here is my test on model js file by using remote method:

```
MyModel.orderproduct = function(id, email, cb){
    MyModel.app.models.Email.send({
        to: email,
        from: 'test@gmail.com',
        subject: 'test subject',
        text : 'my text',
        html : 'my <em> html </em>'
    }, function(err, mail){
        console.log('email sent!' + mail);
        cb(err);
    });

}

MyModel.remoteMethod('orderproduct',{
    accepts:[{arg:'id',type : 'string', required: true},
            {arg: 'email', type : 'string', required : true}],
    http: {path : '/product/:id', verb : 'get',source: 'query'},
    return:{arg : 'res', type : 'Object'}
});
```

I got request was successful status to my remote method. But I got error from mail connector component as :

```
{"error": {
"statusCode": 500,
"name": "Error",
"message": "connect ETIMEDOUT 125.235.4.59:50",
"errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
"code": "ECONNECTION",
"syscall": "connect",
"address": "125.235.4.59",
"port": 50,
"command": "CONN",
"stack": "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 125.235.4.59:50\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1189:14)"
```

}
}

Someone kindly give some advanced or tutorial to using mail connector of Loopback framework.
Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in configuration of `SMTP` server. Port number should be `465` instead of `50`. Use following configuration

```
"transports": [{
    "type": "SMTP",
    "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "secure": true,
    "port": 465,
    "auth": {
      "user": "name@gmail.com",
      "pass": "pass"
    }
  }]
```

Ref: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Email-connector.html#using-gmail

Comment: Thank for quickly reply. But I'm already to use 465 port for my configuration. But I got same error :

{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "connect ETIMEDOUT 125.235.4.59:465",
    "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "code": "ECONNECTION",
    "syscall": "connect",
    "address": "125.235.4.59",
    "port": 465,
    "command": "CONN",
    "stack": "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 125.235.4.59:465\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1189:14)"
  }
}

Comment: Check for server name. There is typo in `stmp.gmail.com`. It should be `smtp.gmail.com`. `stmp` -> `smtp`

Comment: @Kumar : Thank so much, It's my mistake. You saved my day. Thanks